# How to get a repeat input's value

Tags: angularjs

ng-repeat's each item get its own scope, but how to get the input value?
In a normal situation, just set a ng-model and refer it through $scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Is thre a way to work around this?

Comment: `ng-model="item.value"` ?

Comment: Yes, it works. Do I have to init the value to ''?

Comment: What happens when you try? AFAIK, no.

Comment: it works, not does not need init.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.value">
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you wanting to retrieve the value from?